# What's a word for a non-communicable (non-contagious) disease that has still spread throughout a population?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, terminology, antonyms

Normally I would use forms of the words *epidemic, pandemic,* or *infection* but these would imply that the disease is contagious. Are there any words that mean a disease has spread but is not contagious?

Eg: "Instances of diabetes have spread throughout the city."

Comment: Are you looking for a word that specifically implies a **lack** of contagion, or simply a word that does not **necessarily** imply it? _Epidemic_ is a perfectly good word for the latter.

Comment: I'm not even sure thinking in terms of *has spread* is helpful if it's not contagious - *has become widespread* might be closer to the mark.  I suppose you could argue that a lifestyle-related disease could spread socially from an initial point of popularity of the cause, but that's stretching it a bit.

Comment: I don't understand how a disease can spread if it is not contagious. Colds and flus are spread through viruses are they not? They are called infectious, contagious means the same thing. If you wanted to say a way of saying new fashion had caught on, and it was spreading like wild fire, then I might understand your question more.

Comment: Some diseases can "spread" through mechanisms other than contagion, especially inherited and lifestyle-related illnesses. The "obesity epidemic" is a well-known example (and a good example of why _epidemic_ is fine for this usage).

Comment: But the OP asks about *disease* "Are there any words that mean a **disease** has spread but is not contagious" Obesity is not a disease, it's a trend, it's life-style choice, it's a worrying phenomenon. As I mentioned previously, if the OP were looking for an expression which described how something catches on, becomes increasingly wide-spread then yes, epidemic is suitable. But he's asking for a disease.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Infectious and contagious don't actually mean the same thing, there is a slight difference, though in general parlance, the words are usually interchangeable. Infectious actually means its transmissable on the air, or airborne; contagious is transmissable by contact/touch.

Comment: @BraddSzonye "It was horrible- there were porkchops *everywhere*"

Comment: @Mari-LouA Obesity is considered a disease by some, but if you don't agree, it's still possible to have an epidemic of malaria, West Nile, cancer, depression, and other non-contagious diseases.

Comment: OK, cancer I concede is a non-contagious disease, but it doesn't spread throughout a population. It is the one highest causes of death in today's society primarily because we are living longer than any of our forefathers. Albeit that curve of longevity is reversing due to diabetes and obesity. But to talk of cancer spreading among a population makes it sound as if it were an infectious disease, unless it was caused by environmental factors, and tumours can be caused by radioactive leaks etc. You could describe that scenario as being epidemic. I hadn't thought of that +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Epidemic* means only that the disease has spread more than expected; *pandemic* that it has spread to other countries. It doesn't have to be contagious — Bradd Szonye is correct in that — but it could be, so if you really want "words that mean a disease has spread *but is not contagious*" epidemic doesn't specifically say that.

You could try [*outbreak*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/outbreak?showCookiePolicy=true):

> a sudden, violent, or spontaneous occurrence, esp of disease or strife

Comment: Unfortunately, _outbreak_ doesn't specify non-contagion any better than _epidemic_ does. In many cases they're synonymous.

Comment: If the outbreak where contagious, wouldn't you call it an epidemic or a contagion?

Comment: No, it's quite common to have an outbreak of chicken pox at a school, for example. That's contagious but not an epidemic.

Comment: Ha I am with Bradd on this one - outbreak and epidemic go hand and hand.  First something is an outbreak and turns into epidemic... could be contagious or not.

Comment: A defining characteristic of an epidemic is how fast it spreads, hence the implication of infection as non-infectious diseases tend not to spread so fast. A defining characteristic of an outbreak is passing attempts to control it, hence the outbreak of chickenpox - it wasn't there but now it is. I figure that on that basis an outbreak implies 'less infectious' than an epidemic.

Comment: But it is clearly **not** a “word that means a disease has spread but is not contagious.” I think it's a reasonable answer, so I'm not going to downvote, but I'm a bit miffed that people are downvoting the heck out of my answer while leaving this one alone, even though they say essentially the same thing.

Comment: With due respect, and with no intention to be pejorative at all, that is probably because I am not giving an answer that has already been rejected in the OP and then telling him that his question is wrong. My answer may not be 100% right (I don't think there is a 100% right answer...) so I am not expecting any upvotes, but it is an attempt to provide a more suitable word. I have upvoted the question though - this one got me thinking.

Comment: @BraddSzonye ~ BTW... I didn't downvote your answer. I prefer to indicate disagreement in comments, as you may have noticed. I think it is fairer as it gives you a chance to respond.

Comment: My answer does **not** tell the OP that “his question is wrong”! If anything, I'm trying to tell him that it's OK to go with his natural inclination to use _epidemic_ because it's useful even in the situation he's describing. Note that I asked for clarification on the question – I didn't simply reject it.

Comment: "The question is incorrect to rule it out." ~ "The question rejects epidemic specifically because it implies contagion – but that is not true!" ~ "The question is ambiguous as written"

Comment: Yes, the question has a dubious premise, and the asker may be limiting himself unnecessarily. I don't think that makes it “wrong,” which implies a value judgment.

Answer (score 2):

In medical/veterinary fields, the word *prevalence* means:

> the total number of cases of a specific disease in existence in a given population at a certain time
>
> (*Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary*, p 920; *Dorland's Illustrated Medical Dictionary* 31st Ed., p 1536)

And the word *prevalent* means:

> widespread occurrence (*Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary*, p 920)

I think you could say that a disease is *prevalent* in a community without necessarily implying that it was spread by contagion. You are just stating that it is now widespread.

Comment: Note: You can't use "prevalent", that's an adjective and doesn't answer your question. You need a noun.

Comment: @HardyStewz, I don't agree that the OP was asking for a noun.

Answer (score 2):

*Endemic* is not applied strictly to diseases, but it connotes both *pervasive* and *entrenched.* You could certainly say that "Obesity is endemic in the United States."

> natural to or characteristic of a specific people or place; native; indigenous: endemic >folkways; countries where high unemployment is endemic.
>
> (dictionary.com)

Apparently it can also be used as a noun specifically to describe a disease, although I (native US English speaker) am not familiar with this usage:

> noun
>   3. an endemic disease.
>
> (dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

First note that [*epidemic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidemic) is an appropriate word even if the disease is non-communicable:

> An epidemic disease is not required to be contagious, and the term has been applied to West Nile fever and the obesity epidemic, among others.

However, if you would prefer a word that has fewer associations with communicable disease, consider [*rampant, rise, sweeping,*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/epidemic) [*upsurge, wave,*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/epidemic) or [*crisis.*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crisis) These words are not specific to disease, but they address its spread without implying contagion. Most of them are suitable to replace *epidemic* as a noun (“the obesity epidemic”); *rampant* and *sweeping* can replace adjectival uses (“epidemic disease”).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question and seems more like a comment.  The "but is not contagious" part was clearly not met since in your answer and your answer states that epidemic could be used either way.  Also the author gave the word epidemic and was not happy with it - rightly so since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I read the question as asking for a word that does not imply contagion. _Epidemic_ is such a word. The question is incorrect to rule it out. If the poster wants a word that specifically means _non_ contagious, it should be more specific. (Although I don't think such a word exists.)

Comment: The OP has already rejected epidemic, and you can't really tell him his question must be wrong. His rejection, plus "is not contagious" suggest that he wants a word for the spread of a non-contagious disease. At least that is the way I read it.

Comment: The question rejects epidemic **specifically** because it implies contagion – but that is **not true**!

Comment: I think the question rejects it because it does not imply non-contagious.  I agree with what you are saying and it is possible there is no word.  But we probably shouldn't offer something that was already there and rejected, and whatever we offer should meet all of the criteria.

Comment: Seriously, I'm having a hard time seeing how this answer is so controversial. Sometimes questions are based on a false premise. Pointing out the problem in an answer is entirely acceptable. You can have an epidemic of depression, cronyism, or countless other non-contagious things.

Comment: We agree with you but epidemic doesn't imply at all that they are not contagious which the question wants.  Which means it is a really good question!

Comment: "Epidemic" *implies* contagion, even if it is not strictly true. Some dictionaries even define epidemic as contagious ~ *'a widespread occurrence of an infectious disease in a community at a particular time'* -> http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/epidemic or *'Spreading rapidly and extensively by infection'* -> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/epidemic

Comment: The question is ambiguous as written, and I have asked for clarification. I seriously doubt, however, that there is any word that implies _widespread disease_ but **not** _contagion._ However, I have added a few words which imply _widespread,_ and are often used in the context of disease. I hope that addresses your concerns with my original answer.

Comment: Maybe... but you can't insist your answer, which has already been rejected, is correct so the question must be wrong! It could be that there is no word that specifically means 'spread of non-contagious disease', especially as non-contagious diseases tend not to spread. Words that mean 'generally widespread' don't really help... the OP wants "words that mean *a disease* has spread".

Comment: Nobody is moving the goalposts, or nit-picking. The problem with your answer is that word you suggest - epidemic - is already rejected in the question. That was said in the first comment under your answer. The only way to improve it would be to give a different answer, but since the point that an epidemic is not strictly contagious even though it is implied is a valid one and has led to some good comments I would just leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call that *the plague of* [ *the disease name* ]. Or perhaps *the blight of* [ *the disease name* ]. Yes, that's the figurative sense, but for some settings that might not present a problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Epidemic" may be used to describe a disease which has spread and is/is not contagious.

I believe you are using epidemic as a noun, and with that in mind I suggest an example for comparison, for fun;

"Normally I would use forms of the words "stage" or "phase" for a period of time, but these would imply the period of time is finished. Are there any "nouns" for a period of time which has occurred but is not finished?"
I've ruled out "stage" as a possible answer for, in my opinion, the word "stage" implies the period of time is finished. As a matter of fact, I rule out all nouns which could be used to describe a period of time which is finished.